# Unable to RDP using stored credentials in a variable

Tags: powershell, credentials, rdp

I am creating a script that provides workstation information for use in our workplace, however I am getting stuck at a point where I have entered my credentials into the `$mycreds` variable, and it works fine when I use `$mycreds` to perform `Get-WmiObject` information. However, when I then use `$mycreds` to RDP to the selected computers, it doesn't allow me to and gives the following error.

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The security
database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation
trust relationship.
At line:1 char:5
+     Start-Process -FilePath "mstsc" -ArgumentList "/v: $mstscpc" -Cre ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I have tried researching to find out if there was a different syntax, or something, but I simply can not find anything.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
function Read-MultiLineInputBoxDialog([string]$Message, [string]$WindowTitle, [string]$DefaultText)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    # Create the Label.
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
    $label.AutoSize = $true
    $label.Text = $Message

    # Create the TextBox used to capture the user's text.
    $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
    $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(575,200)
    $textBox.AcceptsReturn = $true
    $textBox.AcceptsTab = $false
    $textBox.Multiline = $true
    $textBox.ScrollBars = 'Both'
    $textBox.Text = $Null

    # Create the OK button.
    $okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(415,250)
    $okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
    $okButton.Text = "OK"
    $okButton.Add_Click({ $form.Tag = $textBox.Text; $form.Close() })

    # Create the Cancel button.
    $cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(510,250)
    $cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
    $cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $cancelButton.Add_Click({ $form.Tag = $null; $form.Close() })

    # Create the form.
    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
    $form.Text = $WindowTitle
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(610,320)
    $form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'
    $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $form.AutoSizeMode = 'GrowAndShrink'
    $form.Topmost = $True
    $form.AcceptButton = $okButton
    $form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
    $form.ShowInTaskbar = $true

    # Add all of the controls to the form.
    $form.Controls.Add($label)
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox)
    $form.Controls.Add($okButton)
    $form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

    # Initialize and show the form.
    $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
    $form.ShowDialog() > $null   # Trash the text of the button that was clicked.

    # Return the text that the user entered.
    return $form.Tag
}
$multiLineText = $null
$multiLineText = Read-MultiLineInputBoxDialog -Message "Enter computer names (one per line), you can mix school regions, but you can't mix school and corp devices.`r`nSchools require the FQDN e.g. WS000012345.GBN.eq.edu.au   Corp only needs the device name." -WindowTitle "Enter Workstation Names"
if (($multiLineText -eq "") -or ($multiLineText -eq $null)) { 
    Exit
} else {
    #Gets the users credentials for their GBN elevated account - this is used throughout the script for authentication

    $mycreds = Get-Credential -Credential "GBN\zz-$env:USERNAME" -Message "Please enter your elevated credentials."
    if (!(Test-Path -Path "C:\Temp\Computers.txt")) {
        New-Item -Path C:\Temp -Name Computers.txt -ItemType File -Force
    }
    $multiLineText | Out-File -FilePath C:\Temp\Computers.txt -Encoding default -Force
    $Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\Computers.txt
    $ComputerTable = @()

    foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
        if ($Computer -ne "") {
            $Computer = $Computer.ToUpper()
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Attempting to connect to " -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$Computer"
            if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
                Write-Host "Connected successfully, loading data to list..." -ForegroundColor Green
                $ComputerList = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                $PCInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Credential $mycreds -ComputerName $Computer | Select-Object Caption, InstallDate, OSArchitecture, CSName, LastBootUpTime
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer Name" -Value $Computer.ToUpper() -Force
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OS Architecture" -Value $PCInfo.OSArchitecture -Force
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Operating System" -Value $PCInfo.Caption -Force
                $InstallDateTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($PCInfo.InstallDate)
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Last Re-Imaged" -Value $InstallDateTime -Force
                $RebootDateTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($PCInfo.LastBootUpTime)
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Last Restarted" -Value $RebootDateTime -Force
                $ComputerTable += $ComputerList
            } else {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta "Your call to $Computer " -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "failed" -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta " please check the number and try again."
                $ComputerList = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer Name" -Value $Computer -Force
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OS Architecture" -Value "No Connection" -Force
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Operating System" -Value "No Connection" -Force
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Last Re-Imaged" -Value "No Connection" -Force
                $ComputerList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Last Restarted" -Value "No Connection" -Force
                $ComputerTable += $ComputerList
            }
        }
    }
}
$Remotes = $ComputerTable | Sort-Object "Computer Name" | Out-GridView -Title "Computer Info" -OutputMode Multiple

foreach ($Remote in $Remotes) {
    $mstscpc = $Remote.'Computer Name'
    Start-Process -FilePath "mstsc" -ArgumentList "/v: $mstscpc" -Credential $mycreds
}

if (Test-Path "C:\Temp\Computers.txt") {
    Remove-Item -Path "C:\Temp\Computers.txt" -Force
}
```

Comment: RDP authentication doesn't work that way. Run `mstsc.exe` directly and enter the credentials when prompted if you don't want to store (plaintext) credentials in an .rdp file.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, so there is no way at all to pass credentials any other way other than creating plain text creds that can't be simply opened and viewed?

Comment: I'm not aware of any.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for the info, much appreciated.